# Using Xpath to replace href links with a string from the same parent node

Tags: php, xpath, syntax, domdocument

I can't seem to get the right expression to modify the href links of a query result with a string (to be set as a new url) taken from another query but on the same parent node. Consider this structure:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class=items>
                <span class="working-link">link-1</span>
                <a href="broken-link">Item 1</a>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class=items>
                <span class="working-link">link-2</span>
                <a href="broken-link">Item 2</a>
            </div>
        </td>           
    </tr>
<table>
```

So far this is what I have come up with but with no result:

```
$xpath = new DomXPath($doc);
$nodeList = $xpath->query("//div[@class='items']");

foreach( $nodeList as $result) {

    $newLink = $xpath->query("//span[@class='working-link']",$result);

    foreach($result->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) { 
    $link->setAttribute('href', $newLink);
    }

    echo $doc->saveHTML($result);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! The issue here was using functions for wrong data types. It should be

```
$newLink =  $xpath->query("span[@class='working-link']",$result)[0];
```

indicating that it's an index of an array. Convert it to string after that for setAttribute to use

```
$link->setAttribute('href', $newLink->textContent);
```

Comment: Also, if the element you're looking for is not directly above the node of your first query, you may use this expression: div//span

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you should never starts a relative XPath with `/` as `/` at the beginning of XPath always references the root document; use `./` instead. In this case `span` is direct child of `div`, so you don't need `//` either :

```
$newLink = $xpath->query("./span[@class='working-link']",$result);
```

or just remove the `./` completely :

```
$newLink = $xpath->query("span[@class='working-link']",$result);
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Have to keep in mind these correct expressions.